# One hot encoding in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science

What should be the total number of columns after you perform one hot encoding on a column in a data set? If there are k columns, should it be k-1 or k.

When I try doing it using model.matrix()
The SEX column is converted into two columns sexm and sexf. That i understand. 
BUT in case of education there are four categories : G,U,H,O
but its converted into three columns. educationu, educationh and educationo.

SO the question is why was the education column split in three columns and not four? How does it affect my model?

Before encoding:

[image]

After encoding:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
#Factorizing the catagorical variables
df$SEX = factor(df$SEX,levels = c(1,2),labels = c('M','F'))

df$EDUCATION = factor(df$EDUCATION,levels = c(1,2,3,4),labels = 
c('G','U','H','O'))

df$MARRIAGE = factor(df$MARRIAGE,levels = c(1,2,3),labels = c('M','S','O'))

#Encoding (Dummy Variable Creation)
df = data.frame(model.matrix(~.-1,df))
```

Here is the view of the raw data

[image]

Comment: Please share the code and data used.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/28354/37113

Comment: This belongs on https://stats.stackexchange.com because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

In reality it doesnt matter much and both are correct. The only thing one needs to be careful about is replicating the same process on the test dataset to get the accurate scoring.

in your 2nd example when n-1 vars are created, the final nth level of the original variable is represented in the data when all the new n-1 variabale are '0'.